# Client / Server issues with Malloc?

Tags: c, sockets, malloc

Part of this assignment I'm working on involves a program that executes commands from a client via a socket. Now the only file I have to edit is my mathServer.c I'm currently stuck on **one** of the several parts from the instructions provided:

Finish the method - doServer(). doServer() should have a loop in which it waits for a client to connect to listenFd. When a client does, it should:

1. malloc() enough memory for 2 integers
2. put the file descriptor from accept() in one of those spaces
3. put the value of threadCount in the other space, and increment 
   threadCount
4. Make a detached thread to handle this new client. I called my function handleClient(), but you may call yours whatever. Pass the address of your malloc()-ed array.

The loop should then go back for another accept().

Here's my doServer:

```
void doServer (int listenFd)
{
  //  I.  Application validity check:

  //  II.  Server clients:
  pthread_t     threadId;
  pthread_attr_t    threadAttr;

  int   threadCount = 0; 

  // YOUR CODE HERE
  int *a;

  while(1) {

    //1. If Malloc was NEVER (outside or inside loop) in this program then 
    // it outputs Thread 0 recieved
    a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);

    accept(getServerFileDescriptor(), NULL, NULL);

    // 2.
    a[0] = getServerFileDescriptor();

    // 3.
    a[1] = threadCount++;

    // ALL 4
    pthread_attr_init(&threadAttr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&threadAttr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    pthread_create(&threadId, &threadAttr, handleClient, &a);

    pthread_join(threadId, NULL); 
    pthread_attr_destroy(&threadAttr);

   }

}
```

Here's my handleClient method:

```
void* handleClient(void* vPtr) {

  // Use another pointer to cast back to int*
  // Save the file descriptor and thread number in local vars
  // free() the memory

  // I wrote these 2 lines.
  int *castMe = (int *)vPtr;
  free(vPtr);

  //  II.B.  Read command:
  char  buffer[BUFFER_LEN];
  char  command;
  int fileNum;

  int fd = castMe[0];
  int threadNum = castMe[1];

  char  text[BUFFER_LEN];
  int   shouldContinue  = 1;

  while  (shouldContinue)
  {
    text[0] = '\0';

    read(fd,buffer,BUFFER_LEN);
    printf("Thread %d received: %s\n",threadNum,buffer);
    sscanf(buffer,"%c %d \"%[^\"]\"",&command,&fileNum,text);

    //printf("Thread %d quitting.\n",threadNum);
    return(NULL);

    // YOUR CODE HERE

  }

}
```

I've discovered whenever I remove **a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2)** and everything associated with malloc it does output **Thread 0 received**. However, when I keep malloc the output is just blank and will not return anything.

At first I thought it was because I didn't free the memory, but the memory is being freed from handleClient correct?

**please note this is not the whole program. Any methods you see here are the professors work. these two methods are my own (your code here). Just assume the professors code works :) **

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your piece of code

```
// I wrote these 2 lines.
int *castMe = (int *)vPtr;
free(vPtr);
```

`free` the memory pointed by `castMe` and when you use it you are dereferencing to non valid memory

```
int fd = castMe[0];       //<----- BOOM
int threadNum = castMe[1];//<----- BOOM
```

It is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Moreover when you wrote ***I remove a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2)*** I guess you leave `a` declaration as is

```
int *a;
```

That is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of a is not pointing to a valid memory address.

Comment: how do I make this valid? I thought I was creating another pointer to cast back to int * and then free the memory.

Comment: The question is: why do you want to free the memory if you need it?

Comment: @Karth: You need to understand the difference between pointers (the address of a house) and memory (a house). You created two addresses for one house. Then you call a demolition team to destroy the house. Then you tell the postman to send your letter to the second address thinking that the second address would lead him to a different house. Alas when he gets there he finds a destroyed house ... you program then crashes (or whatever, the behavior is undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the bug:

```
int *castMe = (int *)vPtr;
free(vPtr);
...
int fd = castMe[0];
```

You deallocate the memory that `vPtr` points at and then later on attempt to access that memory through another pointer.

Comment: How can I use another pointer to cast back to int *? Then when I free the memory which pointer am I freeing if that makes sense...

Comment: @Karth You don't "free pointers", you free what they point at. As for the cast, it is superfluous.

Comment: @Karth: To do what you want is not about pointers. It's about memory. Thus you cannot just create a pointer you need to memcpy the memory (which you ALSO must free later). Once you memcpy the memory you may free the old memory. C memory management is highly manual

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
pthread_create(&threadId, &threadAttr, handleClient, &a);
                                                     ^
                                                     |
                                                    WAT
```

Is a problem, since here you make the pthreads library pass the *address of the pointer to the first element in `a`* to the thread, where you meant to pass just a pointer to the first element in `a`.

So, you should have passed `&a[0]`, which is more easily and clearly written as just `a`.

This call doesn't match how you then use the argument inside the thread function. You can print the two to see the difference:

```
printf("&a=%p\n", (void *) &a);
```

and then in the function add:

```
printf("castMe=%p\n", (void *) castMe);
```

The values will be different.

Also, your memory handling is off, never `free()` data that you still need. And in C you don't need explicit casts to/from data pointers and `void *`, you can just do:

```
int * const numbers = vPtr;
```

Comment: What should the pthread_create contain instead of &a. Isn't that the address of my malloc()-ed array?

Comment: @Karth Oops, I failed to mention it straight out, fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

is this answered? I am working on this too!